# FlashPrint visual glitch on Linux (Debian testing)

Tags: linux, flashprint

I have a problem with all versions of FlashPrint on Linux (Linux Debian 5.4.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 5.4.19-1 (2020-02-13) x86_64 GNU/Linux).

I tried to install versions from 3.28 to the latest 4.2, and it's always the same problem, when I try to preview the print, I see a purple glitch.

I think it's more a dependency problem, but if someone car help me figuring this out, it will be great.

[image: Before]
[image: After]

I have no error when I launch in a console, and here is the dependency :

```
ldd FlashPrint 
linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007fff1d3ea000)
libGLU.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLU.so.1 (0x00007f57cb19f000)
librt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0x00007f57cb194000)
libudev.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libudev.so.1 (0x00007f57cb169000)
libQt5OpenGL.so.5 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5OpenGL.so.5 (0x00007f57cb10f000)
libQt5Widgets.so.5 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Widgets.so.5 (0x00007f57caa8a000)
libQt5Gui.so.5 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Gui.so.5 (0x00007f57ca4ae000)
libQt5Network.so.5 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Network.so.5 (0x00007f57ca2f1000)
libQt5Xml.so.5 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Xml.so.5 (0x00007f57ca2b0000)
libQt5Core.so.5 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5 (0x00007f57c9d76000)
libGL.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1 (0x00007f57c9cef000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f57c9cce000)
libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f57c9b89000)
libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f57c9b6d000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f57c99aa000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f57cb25c000)
libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f57c97dd000)
libpng16.so.16 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng16.so.16 (0x00007f57c97a4000)
libz.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0x00007f57c9787000)
libharfbuzz.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libharfbuzz.so.0 (0x00007f57c9682000)
libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f57c967b000)
libicui18n.so.63 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicui18n.so.63 (0x00007f57c93a4000)
libicuuc.so.63 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicuuc.so.63 (0x00007f57c91d3000)
libpcre2-16.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre2-16.so.0 (0x00007f57c9150000)
libdouble-conversion.so.3 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdouble-conversion.so.3 (0x00007f57c9139000)
libglib-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f57c9010000)
libGLdispatch.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLdispatch.so.0 (0x00007f57c8f58000)
libGLX.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLX.so.0 (0x00007f57c8f24000)
libfreetype.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfreetype.so.6 (0x00007f57c8e65000)
libgraphite2.so.3 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgraphite2.so.3 (0x00007f57c8e39000)
libicudata.so.63 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicudata.so.63 (0x00007f57c7448000)
libpcre.so.3 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre.so.3 (0x00007f57c73d2000)
libX11.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6 (0x00007f57c7290000)
libxcb.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1 (0x00007f57c7266000)
libXau.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXau.so.6 (0x00007f57c7062000)
libXdmcp.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXdmcp.so.6 (0x00007f57c6e5c000)
libbsd.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libbsd.so.0 (0x00007f57c6e40000)
```

Comment: Bug reports are not something we deal with here sadly - please report the bug to the development board of Flashprint.

Comment: Hi, sorry about that, I just can't fill out a bug report, the app is freezing and nothing happen when I try to click on "feedback".
(Yeah, I am a nightmare customer to deal with xD)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the open-source niceties of OpenGL, you need to will often need to install and update the drivers for your GPU.  If you do not wish to or cannot utilize your GPU (it'll cost you in performance), look for options to turn off hardware acceleration or use a purely "software renderer" typesetting.

I don't know if FlashPrint has such settings, but I do know that OpenGL can do some screwy stuff if you lack correct Nvidia drivers (and have an Nvidia GPU).

Comment: First : Thank you for helping me. The thing is : I have a proper install of nvidia drivers, I play a lot of games, but yeah forcing a software rendering is a very good idea (I have a powerfull CPU).